# How to output formated text but with added values - Python

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and I can´t find any way to execute this code.

I am using JSON generator and need to print formated code and add some changes to it. I have variables that have some values and I need to insert them into my code. So the final code will have exact formating but with added values.

```html
hp = 50;
cp = 100;
wp = 40;

{
  "721": {
    "<policy_id>": {
      "<asset_name>": {
        "name": "<display_name>",
        "image": "<ipfs_link>",
        "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
        "description": "<description>",
        "Visual": "<rarity>",
        "Health Points": "<hp (value of hp here)>",
        "Combat Power": "<cp (value of cp here)>",
        "Working Power": "<wp (value of wp here)>",
        "files": [
          {
            "name": "<display_name>",
            "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
            "src": "<ipfs_link>"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Final output (I want to generate 100 of this same code with exact formating but with different hp wp and cp values.

```html
{
  "721": {
    "<policy_id>": {
      "<asset_name>": {
        "name": "<display_name>",
        "image": "<ipfs_link>",
        "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
        "description": "<description>",
        "Visual": "<rarity>",
        "Health Points": "50",
        "Combat Power": "100",
        "Working Power": "40",
        "files": [
          {
            "name": "<display_name>",
            "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
            "src": "<ipfs_link>"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: "Health Points": "<hp (value of hp here)>", instead doing that do this: "Health Points": variable_name    don't use quotes, just put in the variable that contains the value you want to add. If you mean you want to have something like "hp: 10" then do this: f"hp: {variable_name}" that is a "format string" - look it up

Comment: Are you looking for `whatever["721"]["<policy id>"]["Health Points"] = hp`?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I want to achive that I have tamplate of code and I need to set different hp wp cp values, but I need to generate the same formated code for each output. Imagine that this second code is just one type and there will be 100 same codes generated but with different hp wp and cp

Comment: Basicaly I have database of game items and all of this items have same json template, but only thing I need to change is wp cf and hp. I want to generate JSON file where will be 100 same code tamplates for each item, but each of them will have diefferent or same value of wp cf and hp. I am basicaly trying to make template code generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but first you need to know what kind of formatting you need, for example how many spaces you want to indent.

**Code**

`json.dumps` accept an indent as an argument to format your json output.

```py
import json

hp = 50;
cp = 100;
wp = 40;

data = {
    "721": {
        "<policy_id>": {
            "<asset_name>": {
                "name": "<display_name>",
                "image": "<ipfs_link>",
                "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
                "description": "<description>",
                "Visual": "<rarity>",
                "Health Points": "<hp (value of hp here)>",
                "Combat Power": "<cp (value of cp here)>",
                "Working Power": "<wp (value of wp here)>",
                "files": [
                    {
                    "name": "<display_name>",
                    "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
                    "src": "<ipfs_link>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

data["721"]["<policy_id>"]["<asset_name>"]["Health Points"] = hp
data["721"]["<policy_id>"]["<asset_name>"]["Combat Power"] = cp
data["721"]["<policy_id>"]["<asset_name>"]["Working Power"] = wp


# Use indent=2 if you prefer less space
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```json
{
    "721": {
        "<policy_id>": {
            "<asset_name>": {
                "name": "<display_name>",
                "image": "<ipfs_link>",
                "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
                "description": "<description>",
                "Visual": "<rarity>",
                "Health Points": 50,
                "Combat Power": 100,
                "Working Power": 40,
                "files": [
                    {
                        "name": "<display_name>",
                        "mediaType": "<mime_type>",
                        "src": "<ipfs_link>"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are loading the JSON from a file or as a string, then you can use the `json.load` or `json.loads` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) to painlessly wrap variables in strings, and [`json.dump/s()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) can produce nice JSONs if an `indent` argument is supplied:

```
import json
hp = 50
whatever = {"721":{"<policy id>":{"<asset name>":{"Health Points":f"{hp}"}}}}
print(json.dumps(whatever, indent=4))
```

will display

> ```
> {
>     "721": {
>         "<policy id>": {
>             "<asset name>": {
>                 "Health Points": "50"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Following error is showing up: https://pasteboard.co/in8Zw7WHiqDT.png
(I am using JSON generator: https://json-generator.com

Answer (score 0):

```
# you don't need semi colon after variable
hp = 50
cp = 100
wp = 40
# use variable name directly without quotes
"Health Points": hp,
"Combat Power": cb,
"Working Power": wp,
```